# How should I handle session timeouts when the client's system time is in the future?

Tags: time, session-timeout, future

Session timeouts work perfectly as expected when a clients' local time is in sync with a UTC server, however if the client has their local time set to some time in the future, they constantly receive session timeout messages and are logged out of the site.

What are some possible solutions to this problem used by other developers? I am sure that I am not the first person to have this problem, however I cannot find much information on it online.

Comment: You probably ought to at least describe what type of session you are talking about here - TCP, SSH, SSL, some sort of web-based protocol, a TTY muxer like screen or tmux, ....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but I worked it out. Before, I was setting a user's session to expire at a certain time, 15 minutes after their last activity. However, that expire date is set based on the UTC server's time, not the user's local time. So when the client's local date/time was compared to the expire date/time it would always cause a timeout for users with local time more than 15 minutes in the future.

I fixed this problem by setting the expire time to be an amount of time (15 minutes) rather than the actual date/time of expiration. That way no matter what the user's local time is, they will timeout 15 minutes after their last activity.